# Audi front axle buzzing/humming sound

Tags: audi, axle, a4

I have this weird buzzing sound with my 2008 Audi A4 (B8) coming - probably - from the front axle. First I thought it was the engine or exhaust making this sound, but the sound is not dependent on engine RPM. Also to mention, the sound is neither dependent on steering/fast cornering like ball bearings usually are.

I changed the driver side ball bearing with no luck of fixing the sound. The sound is very audible at around 50kmh and it increases its pitch when speed is increased.

Driver side CV joints were in normal shape, so I believe that the passenger side is as well. What could be making the sound?

Comment: Does it change based on throttle input (eg: more throttle = louder)?  What I do with random noises is ask a passenger to point out where they think the noise is coming from.  The harmonics inside a vehicle can be very misleading.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Speed dependent but not RPM dependent noises may also point to the transmission or differential.